# Statistical understanding specific Adaboost algorithm modification

Tags: adaboost, object-detection

I'm working with the paper ["Face Detection with the Modified Census Transform"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.456.9034&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Some things in this paper are not clear for me.

I have written below my understanding and interpretation of the algorithm, described in this paper, and kindly ask to comment on them and correct me if I'm wrong.

The paper describes face detector, similar to the one, suggested by Viola and Jones. This face detector uses sliding window over the image, transformed with the [Modified Census Transform (MCT)](https://www.slideshare.net/myditto/modified-census-transform).

It seems to the that the detector looks at certain pixels inside that window, calculates their weighted sums and compares them to thresholds.

Authors use a version of the Adaboost to construct a cascade of elementary classifiers (I would call them "moderate-strength"), each of which consists of several weak classifiers. Each weak classifier is a sum of weights, assigned to pixels, selected during boosting. Pixel positions are also selected in the boosting procedure.

What is unclear for me is the underlying theory for "Boosting the sparse local structure net" and "Training of a weak structure feature classifier", described in Tables 1 and 2 on page 5 in the link above.

During each boosting round $t$ in $(1..T)$:

1. two lookup tables are constructed, for all possible pixel positions (in the window) and all possible MCT values (0..511):

$g^0_t(\mathbf{x}, \gamma) = \sum_{i}{D_t(i)I(\Gamma_i(\mathbf x) = \gamma)I(c_i=0)}$ 
and 
$g^1_t(\mathbf{x}, \gamma) = \sum_{i}{D_t(i)I(\Gamma_i(\mathbf x) = \gamma)I(c_i=1)}$,

where:

$t$ is a number of the boosting round,

$\mathbf{x}$ is a location of a pixel (a number, if we span a 2D image in a 1D string),

$\gamma$ is a pixel value (0..511),

$D_t(i)$ is a weight of $i$-th training sample, assigned by the Adaboost in the round $t$,

$I()$ is the indicator function, returning 1 if its argument is true and 0 otherwise,

$\Gamma_i$ is the MCT-transformed image of  $i$-th training sample,  $\Gamma_i(\mathbf x)$ is the value of that pixel on that image,

$c_i$ is a class of $i$-th training sample (0 - not face, 1 - face),

As I understand, these tables $g^0_t(\mathbf{x}, \gamma), g^1_t(\mathbf{x}, \gamma)$ contain conditional probabilities of "not face"/"face", given we've got the value $\gamma$ in the pixel with position $\mathbf x$. Is my understanding correct?

2. errors are calculated for each lookup table: 
   $\epsilon_t(\mathbf x) = \sum_{\gamma}min\{g_t^0(\mathbf x, \gamma), g_t^1(\mathbf x, \gamma)\}$

Calculation of the error $\epsilon_t(\mathbf x)$ is unclear. In fact, these errors are calculated for each pixel location, not for each lookup table. And the same relation between $g_t^0(\mathbf x, \gamma)$ and $g_t^1(\mathbf x, \gamma)$ is used below in construction of a lookup table $w_t(\gamma)$.

I suspect, this should be a probability of incorrect classification, if we select the pixel $\mathbf x$, but why is it calculated in such way (sum of minimum probabilities)?

3. The pixel position $\mathbf {x}_t$ with the best (lowest) error $\epsilon_t$ is selected. This step also involves recording of the selected pixel position, for the case, when number of boosting rounds is greater than maximum allowed pixel positions.
4. Create a lookup table $w_t(\gamma)$ showing whether to include results, obtained in current boosting round $t$ for this pixel, in the final weighted sum of the moderate classifier $h_{\mathbf x}(\gamma)$:

$w_t(\gamma) = \begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } g_t^0(\mathbf{x}_t, \gamma)>g_t^1(\mathbf{x}_t, \gamma)\\
    1,& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

In fact, this table is a 512 element vector, each element of which is 1, if "face" weight $g_t^1$ of the pixel $\mathbf{x}_t$ is equal to or greater than its "non-face" weight $g_t^0$ and 0 otherwise.

5. Then weights $D_t(i)$ are updated according to the original rule from the Adaboost algorithm (calculate power of exponent $\alpha_t$, multiply by exponent and normalize so that they form a distribution, that is, sum to 1).

So, we've got the following in the end of each boosting round:

- selected position $\mathbf{x}_t$
- its weight $\alpha_t$
- array of 512 ones and zeros, indicating decisions (face/not face) that should be taken depending on pixel value $\gamma$ observed in selected position $\mathbf{x}_t$

As I understand, these results constitute current weak classifier (working with a single pixel).

And after $T$ boosting rounds we've got the following:

- list of selected positions $\mathbf{x}_t$ of $T$ items, some of them are repeated -> we can easily get the list of unique selected positions from them
- list of weights $\alpha_t$ of $T$ items
- 2D array of dimensions $512 \times T$ of 0 and 1, where each cell indicates whether we include respective $\alpha_t$ in the summand number $t$, depending on the pixel value $\gamma$

The resulting elementary classifier  $h_{\mathbf x}(\gamma)$ is constructed after $T$ boosting rounds from the list above:

$$
h_{\mathbf x}(\gamma) = \sum_{i=1}^{T}{\alpha_t}w_t(\gamma)I(\mathbf x = \mathbf{x}_t) 
$$

That is, given a pixel location $\mathbf x$ and its MCT value $\Gamma(\mathbf x)$, this classifier returns either 0, if the pixel not in the set of selected $\mathbf{x}_t$, or the sum of several $\alpha_t$'s, corresponding to non-zero values in $w_t(\gamma)$. I think, this value can be considered as a probability that this pixel belongs to a face.

Two things are not clear for me.

What do 0 and 1 in $w_t$ mean? Are these class labels or indicators showing whether to include respective $\alpha_t$ in sum?

How to calculate thresholds, used to choose between face and non-face?